# How to use Junit testing for insert operation in Java

Tags: java, jdbc, junit, crud

I got an assignment to do a JDBC CRUD operation with MySQL,

This is the sample code I got it,

**DB Setup:**

```
CREATE DATABASE 'demo';
USE demo;

create table users (
    id  int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(220) NOT NULL,
    country varchar(120),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

package net.javaguides.usermanagement.dao;
```

**CRUD File:**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import net.javaguides.usermanagement.model.User;

/**
 * AbstractDAO.java This DAO class provides CRUD database operations for the
 * table users in the database.
 * 
 * @author sourcecodeexamples
 *
 */
public class UserDAO {
    private String jdbcURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo?useSSL=false";
    private String jdbcUsername = "root";
    private String jdbcPassword = "root";

    private static final String INSERT_USERS_SQL = "INSERT INTO users" + "  (name, email, country) VALUES " +
        " (?, ?, ?);";

    private static final String SELECT_USER_BY_ID = "select id,name,email,country from users where id =?";
    private static final String SELECT_ALL_USERS = "select * from users";
    private static final String DELETE_USERS_SQL = "delete from users where id = ?;";
    private static final String UPDATE_USERS_SQL = "update users set name = ?,email= ?, country =? where id = ?;";

    public UserDAO() {}

    protected Connection getConnection() {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, jdbcUsername, jdbcPassword);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }

    public void insertUser(User user) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println(INSERT_USERS_SQL);
        // try-with-resource statement will auto close the connection.
        try (Connection connection = getConnection(); PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_USERS_SQL)) {
            preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getName());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getEmail());
            preparedStatement.setString(3, user.getCountry());
            System.out.println(preparedStatement);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            printSQLException(e);
        }
    }

    public User selectUser(int id) {
        User user = null;
        // Step 1: Establishing a Connection
        try (Connection connection = getConnection();
            // Step 2:Create a statement using connection object
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SELECT_USER_BY_ID);) {
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
            System.out.println(preparedStatement);
            // Step 3: Execute the query or update query
            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            // Step 4: Process the ResultSet object.
            while (rs.next()) {
                String name = rs.getString("name");
                String email = rs.getString("email");
                String country = rs.getString("country");
                user = new User(id, name, email, country);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            printSQLException(e);
        }
        return user;
    }

    public List < User > selectAllUsers() {

        // using try-with-resources to avoid closing resources (boiler plate code)
        List < User > users = new ArrayList < > ();
        // Step 1: Establishing a Connection
        try (Connection connection = getConnection();

            // Step 2:Create a statement using connection object
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SELECT_ALL_USERS);) {
            System.out.println(preparedStatement);
            // Step 3: Execute the query or update query
            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            // Step 4: Process the ResultSet object.
            while (rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt("id");
                String name = rs.getString("name");
                String email = rs.getString("email");
                String country = rs.getString("country");
                users.add(new User(id, name, email, country));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            printSQLException(e);
        }
        return users;
    }

    public boolean deleteUser(int id) throws SQLException {
        boolean rowDeleted;
        try (Connection connection = getConnection(); PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(DELETE_USERS_SQL);) {
            statement.setInt(1, id);
            rowDeleted = statement.executeUpdate() > 0;
        }
        return rowDeleted;
    }

    public boolean updateUser(User user) throws SQLException {
        boolean rowUpdated;
        try (Connection connection = getConnection(); PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(UPDATE_USERS_SQL);) {
            statement.setString(1, user.getName());
            statement.setString(2, user.getEmail());
            statement.setString(3, user.getCountry());
            statement.setInt(4, user.getId());

            rowUpdated = statement.executeUpdate() > 0;
        }
        return rowUpdated;
    }

    private void printSQLException(SQLException ex) {
        for (Throwable e: ex) {
            if (e instanceof SQLException) {
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                System.err.println("SQLState: " + ((SQLException) e).getSQLState());
                System.err.println("Error Code: " + ((SQLException) e).getErrorCode());
                System.err.println("Message: " + e.getMessage());
                Throwable t = ex.getCause();
                while (t != null) {
                    System.out.println("Cause: " + t);
                    t = t.getCause();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is they asked to do JUnit testing for insert operation. I am completely new to this Java domain, so can anyone please provide information what should I need to include in this code.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend a [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5) on JUnit 5.

Here are some steps to try:

1. Add JUnit 5 to your project dependencies. Easy to do if you use [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.8.2).
2. Add a new JUnit class to your `/test` folder in the same package as `UserDAO`.
3. Give the UserDAOTest class an instance of the `UserDAO` class and call its methods.  Create happy path and failure test cases to make sure the class is behaving as it should in all cases.

Here's a template to start with:

```
public class UserDAOTest {

    // You have to initialize this object
    private UserDAO userDao;

    @Test
    public void testInsert_Success() {
        // setup
        // Initialize test user data
        User expected = new User();
        // exercise
        this.userDAO.insertUser(expected);
        // assert
        User actual = this.userDAO.selectUser(expected.getId());
        Assertions.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I ask anything wrong, do I need to add this code in that new Junit class file inside the test folder?

Comment: Yes, it's a new class.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and one last question, the code you provided is enough right?

Comment: No, not enough.  This is a hint to send you off to research what would be enough.  Ask yourself: how would I prove that my INSERT into the database worked?  Same for any other method.  You cannot expect me to write this code for you.